# Printing an array in order with fork()

Tags: c, fork

i'm trying to print an array with help of fork, where every element will be printed by a seperate child process.

```
void printArray_fork(int *p_array, int length){
    int i;

    pid_t pid;
    for(i = 0; i<length;i++){
        /* Create children procs */
        pid = fork();
        if(pid==0){
            break;
        }
    }

    if(pid == 0) {
            printf( "My process ID : %d value: %d\n",getpid(),*(p_array + i));
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that I want it also to be in order (ascending or descending, doesnt matter) How would I do that?

Comment: `fork` does not print an array. It creates a new process. You need to `waitpid` it in the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a little modification of your code to print in order.

```
  /* Create children procs */
     pid = fork();
     wait();
```

As suggested above, all you need is to use wait for the next child process to be created.